# magento edit quantity without redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, magento

we have a marketplace site. each seller/vendor have their own account.

we are displaying list of *sellers products , qty, sku*...etc in their account.

http://prntscr.com/8vgul0

we are using this code to display those information :

```
<?php 
$isPartner= Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->isPartner(); 
$helper= Mage::helper('marketplace');
if($isPartner==1){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
    </script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1 style="float:left;"><?php echo $helper->__('My Product List') ?></h1>
    </div>  
    <div class="wk_mp_design">
        <div class="block block-account">   
            <div class="block-title">   
                <strong><span><h4><?php echo $helper->__('Product List') ?></h4></span></strong>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fieldset wk_mp_fieldset">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="hor-scroll">
                    <form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" method="post">
                        <table cellspacing="0" class="border wk_mp_list_table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr id="wk_mp_tr_heading">
                                    <th><span><?php echo $helper->__('Product Name') ?></span></th>
                                    <th><span><?php echo $helper->__('Date') ?></span></th>
                                    <th><span><?php echo $helper->__('Product Status') ?></span></th>
                                    <th><span>&nbsp;</span></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="wk_mp_body">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="s" placeholder='<?php echo $helper->__('Search by product name') ?>' value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('s')?>"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="wk_mp_td_span">
                                            <?php echo $helper->__('From: ') ?>
                                            <input name="from_date" id="special_from_date" class="input-text" value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('from_date')?>" />
                                        </span>                             
                                        <span class="wk_mp_td_span">
                                            <?php echo $helper->__('To: ') ?>
                                            <input name="to_date" id="special_to_date" class="input-text" value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('to_date')?>" />
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="prostatus" class="input-text">
                                            <option value=""><?php echo $helper->__('All') ?></option>
                                            <option value="1" <?php if($this->getRequest()->getParam('prostatus') == 1) echo 'selected="selected"'?>>
                                                <?php echo $helper->__('Approved') ?>
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="2" <?php if($this->getRequest()->getParam('prostatus') == 2) echo 'selected="selected"'?>>
                                                <?php echo $helper->__('Unapproved') ?>
                                            </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button class="button" title="Save" type="submit">
                                            <span><span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Submit') ?></span></span></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                    <?php 
                    if(count($this->getCollection())==0){ ?>        
                        <div class="fieldset wk_mp_fieldset">
                            <div class="wk_emptymsg">
                                <?php echo $helper->__('No Product Available') ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php 
                    } else{ ?>
                        <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/massdeletesellerpro') ?>" method="post" id="formmassdelete" name="formmassdelete">
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
                            <button class="button" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Delete Products') ?>" type="submit" style="float: left;padding: 5px 5px 5px 0;"  id="mass_delete_butn">
                                <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Delete Products') ?></span></span>
                            </button>
                            <table cellspacing="0" class="border wk_mp_list_table wk_mp_list_container_table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="wk_content">
                                        <th class="wk_check_first_td">
                                            <span>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="mpselecctall" value="all" id="mpselecctall"/>
                                            </span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="wk_first_td">
                                            <span class="label name">
                                                <?php echo $helper->__('Product')?>
                                            </span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="wk_first_td">
                                            <span class="label name">
                                                <?php echo $helper->__('sku')?>
                                            </span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <span class="label pro_status">
                                                <?php echo $helper->__('Status')?>
                                            </span>
                                        </th>

                                        <!--
                                        <th>
                                            <span class="label qty">
                                                <?php echo $helper->__('Qty. Confirmed')?>
                                            </span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <span class="label qty">
                                                <?php echo $helper->__('Qty. Pending')?>
                                            </span>
                                        </th>   
                                        <th>
                                            <span class="label qty">
                                                <?php echo $helper->__('Qty. Sold')?>
                                            </span>
                                        </th>
                                        -->
                                        <th>
                                            <span class="label">
                                                <?php echo $helper->__('Qty')?>
                                            </span>
                                        </th>

                                        <th>
                                            <span class="label">
                                                <?php echo $helper->__('Earn Amount')?>
                                            </span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <span class="label">
                                                <?php echo $helper->__('Action')?>
                                            </span>
                                        </th>                       
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php 
                                    $i = 0;
                                    foreach($this->getCollection() as $products){
                                        $i++;
                                        $productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');
                                        $salesdetail=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getSalesdetail($products->getEntityId());
                                        ?>
                                        <tr class="wk_row_view <?php echo $class = ($i == count($this->getCollection()))? 'wk_last_tr':''?>">
                                            <td class="wk_check_first_td">
                                                <span>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="product_mass_delete[]" class="mpcheckbox" value="<?php echo $products->getEntityId(); ?>"/>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="wk_first_td">
                                                <input type="hidden" class="hidden_id" value="<?php echo $products->getEntityId(); ?>" />
                                                <div class="label name" title="<?php echo $products->getName(); ?>">
                                                    <div class="wk_pro_divide1">
                                                        <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($products,'thumbnail');?>" class="image" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="wk_pro_divide2">
                                                        <div style="width:100%;">
                                                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl($products->getUrlPath())?>" target="blank">
                                                                <?php echo $products->getName();?>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
                                                            <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false);?>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                            <?php echo $sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($products->getId())->getSku();?>
                                            </td>


                                            <?php 
                                            if($products->getStatus()==2) { ?>
                                                <td>        
                                                    <span class="label pro_status">
                                                        <?php echo $helper->__('Pending')?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="label qty">
                                                        <?php echo $helper->__('Pending')?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="label qty">
                                                        <?php echo $helper->__('Pending')?>
                                                    </span> 
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="label qty">
                                                        <?php echo $helper->__('Pending')?>
                                                    </span> 
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="label qty">
                                                        <?php echo $helper->__('Pending')?>
                                                    </span> 
                                                </td>                                   
                                            <?php }
                                            else{ 
                                                $id=$products->getId();
                                                $productsolddetail=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getProductSalesDetailById($id);
                                                $qtycom=0;
                                                $com=0;
                                                foreach($productsolddetail as $key){
                                                    $qtycom+=$key['magequantity'];
                                                    $com+=$key['actualparterprocost'];
                                                }   ?>

                                                <td>        
                                                    <span class="label pro_status">
                                                        <?php echo $helper->__('Approved')?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>

                                                <!--    edit qty -->
                                                <td>

                                                <?php echo (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>

                                                     <span class="label wk_action">
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>" data-type="<?php echo $products->getTypeId(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $helper->__('Edit')?>" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Edit')?>" class="mp_edit"/>

                                                     </span>    
                                                </td>

                                               <!-- edit qty end -->


                                                <!--
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="label qty">
                                                        <?php echo $salesdetail['quantitysoldconfirmed']; ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="label qty">
                                                        <?php echo $salesdetail['quantitysoldpending']; ?>
                                                    </span> 
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="label qty">
                                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/salesdetail/')."id/".$products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $salesdetail['quantitysold']; ?></a>
                                                    </span> 
                                                </td>
                                                -->
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="label price">
                                                        <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($salesdetail['amountearned'], true, false); ?>
                                                    </span> 
                                                </td>
                                                <?php 
                                            }?>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="label wk_action">
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>" data-type="<?php echo $products->getTypeId(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $helper->__('Edit')?>" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Edit')?>" class="mp_edit"/>
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-trash.png'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $helper->__('Delete')?>" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Delete')?>" class="mp_delete"/>
                                                </span> 
                                            </td>                       
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                    }?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                        <?php
                    }?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>        
        </div>  
        <div class="buttons-set">
            <p class="back-link">
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript: window.history.back();" class="left">&laquo; <?php echo $helper->__('Back') ?></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script> 
    var $wk_jq=jQuery.noConflict();
    var newCustomerProductForm1 = new VarienForm('formmassdelete', true);
    (function($wk_jq){
        $wk_jq( "#special_from_date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
        $wk_jq( "#special_to_date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
        $wk_jq('body').delegate('.mp_edit','click',function(){
            var id=$wk_jq(this).parents('.wk_row_view').find('.hidden_id').val();   
            var dicision=confirm('<?php echo $helper->__(" Are you sure you want to edit this product ? ")?>');
            if(dicision==true){         
                var $type_id=$wk_jq(this).attr('data-type');                
                if($type_id=='simple')
                    window.location = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editapprovedsimple/') ?>".concat("id/",id); 
                if($type_id=='downloadable')
                    window.location = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editapproveddownloadable/') ?>".concat("id/",id);           
                if($type_id=='virtual')
                    window.location = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editapprovedvirtual/') ?>".concat("id/",id);        
                if($type_id=='configurable')
                    window.location = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editapprovedconfigurable/') ?>".concat("id/",id);
                if($type_id=='grouped')
                    window.location = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpgroupproduct/index/editapprovedgrouped/') ?>".concat("id/",id);
                    <?php
                    //echo $this->getChildHtml('mpgrouped_productslist');
                    // echo $this->getChildHtml('mpbundle_productslist');
                    ?>
                if($type_id=='bundle')
                    window.location = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpbundleproduct/index/editbundle/') ?>".concat("id/",id);
            }
        });
        $wk_jq('#mass_delete_butn').click(function(e){
            var flag =0;
            $wk_jq('.mpcheckbox').each(function(){
                if (this.checked == true){
                    flag =1;
                }
            });
            if (flag == 0){
                alert("<?php echo $helper->__(' No Checkbox is checked ') ?>");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                var dicisionapp=confirm('<?php echo $helper->__(" Are you sure you want to delete these product ? ")?>');
                if(dicisionapp==true){
                    $wk_jq('#form-customer-product-new').submit();
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        $wk_jq('#mpselecctall').click(function(event) {
            if(this.checked) {
                $wk_jq('.mpcheckbox').each(function() {
                    this.checked = true;      
                });
            }else{
                $wk_jq('.mpcheckbox').each(function() {
                    this.checked = false;           
                });         
            }
        });

        $wk_jq('.mp_delete').click(function(){
            var id=$wk_jq(this).parents('.wk_row_view').find('.hidden_id').val();
            var dicisionapp=confirm('<?php echo $helper->__(" Are you sure you want to delete this product ? ")?>');
            if(dicisionapp==true)
                window.location = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/delete/') ?>".concat("id/",id);
        });
    })($wk_jq);
    </script>
    <?php 
}else{
    echo "<h2 class='wk_new_msg'>".$helper->__("To BECOME SELLER PLEASE CONTACT TO ADMIN.")."</h2>";
}?>
```

we have a edit button next to "Qty", if we click on that edit button, its redirecting to another page and than seller edit the information and save it.

we are using following code to edit :

```
<span class="label wk_action">
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>" data-type="<?php echo $products->getTypeId(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $helper->__('Edit')?>" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Edit')?>" class="mp_edit"/>

</span>
```

what we need is if we click on "edit" button, then it should display text field as like in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNCaT.png) and update and cancel button below.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below URL for admin grid:

http://www.atwix.com/magento/inline-editing-in-magento-backend-grids/

I'm not sure but this may help you. Try below for front-end :

**Step 1 :**    Make onclick event on your edit image and call javascript function

```
eg :  onclick="updateField(this, '. $product_id .'); return false";
```

**Step 2 :** Create javascript function which you have define in onclick of image.

```
<?php $url='Mage::getUrl('module_name/index/updateField/');' ?>
<script type="text/javascript">

function updateField(image, product_id)
{
    new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $url ?>', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: { id: fieldId, field: $(button).previous('input').getValue() }
    });
}
</script>
```

**Step: 3**     Make function in your controller that you have define in java script ajax url.

```
public function updateFieldAction()
{
    $fieldId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $field = $this->getRequest()->getParam('field');
    if ($fieldId) {
        $model = Mage::getModel('modulename/model')->load($fieldId);
        $model->setField($field);
        $model->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is related frontend, can you please give me what code  i have to do?

Comment: i updated step 1 and step 2 code in myproductlist.phtml . i used 3rd step code in "app/code/local/extension name/module name/controllers/shipping.php" but its not working. please check : http://pastebin.com/hhWrn1gk and http://pastebin.com/MBtE2hcS

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HV6YKVXA:  i added from line 12 to 21 in above code, but its not saving the quantity. if i click on update button, i am getting message " product is deleted

Comment: hi, updating the quantity is working only for first product, please help me to find solution